# Problem with resetting array when displaying numbers

Tags: arrays, reset

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to make random numbers every time the user clicks a button. But now the numbers are added to the end of the array and therefor more numbers appear instead of a total reset.

Can somebody help me ?

Here is what I tried so far **:**

```js
let randomNumbersArray = [];
const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container");
let numbersEl = document.querySelector(".numbers")
const randomNumberBtn = document.querySelector("#random-number-btn");
const showRandomNumbersEl = document.querySelector(".showRandomNumbers");

function getRandomNumbers(numbers, amount) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
        randomNumbersArray.push(randomNumber);

    }
}

function showRandomNumbers() {
    for (let y = 0; y < randomNumbersArray.length; y++) {

        showRandomNumbersEl.innerHTML += `<div class="numbers">${randomNumbersArray[y]}</div>`

    }
}

randomNumberBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    getRandomNumbers(10, 1000);
    showRandomNumbers();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.showRandomNumbers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 42px);
    text-align: center;
    gap: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.showRandomNumbers div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="listOfNumbers">
            <h4>How many random numbers?</h4>
            <input type="text" id="number-random-numbers">
            <button id="random-number-btn">Get numbers</button>
        </div>
        <div class="showRandomNumbers">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this (read comments):

```js
function getRandomNumbers(numbers, amount) {
    // basically your creating a new array each time you call the function
    randomNumbersArray = Array(numbers).fill(undefined).map(_ => Math.floor(Math.random() * amount))
}
function showRandomNumbers() {
    // here i reset the content of the container each time you call the function so every time it just shows the new ones
    showRandomNumbersEl.innerHTML = '';
    for (const rndNumber of randomNumbersArray) {
        showRandomNumbersEl.innerHTML += `<div class="numbers">${rndNumber}</div>`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obseravtions/Suggestions **:**

- Empty `randomNumbersArray` array before pushing new set of random numbers.
- `showRandomNumbersEl.innerHTML` should be empty before showing the new set of records in `showRandomNumbers()` method

Demo **:**

```js
let randomNumbersArray = [];
const containerEl = document.querySelector(".container");
let numbersEl = document.querySelector(".numbers")
const randomNumberBtn = document.querySelector("#random-number-btn");
const showRandomNumbersEl = document.querySelector(".showRandomNumbers");

function getRandomNumbers(numbers, amount) {
    randomNumbersArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
        randomNumbersArray.push(randomNumber);

    }
}

function showRandomNumbers() {
    showRandomNumbersEl.innerHTML = '';
    for (let y = 0; y < randomNumbersArray.length; y++) {

        showRandomNumbersEl.innerHTML += `<div class="numbers">${randomNumbersArray[y]}</div>`

    }
}

randomNumberBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    getRandomNumbers(10, 1000);
    showRandomNumbers();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.showRandomNumbers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 42px);
    text-align: center;
    gap: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.showRandomNumbers div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="listOfNumbers">
            <h4>How many random numbers?</h4>
            <input type="text" id="number-random-numbers">
            <button id="random-number-btn">Get numbers</button>
        </div>
        <div class="showRandomNumbers">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```